# CKeditor: Add class to all ul and ol elements on output

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

The ul and ol elements are often used in theming outside of the 'text'-context (e.g. category blocks, etc.). Therefore the bullets are removed by default.

Is there a way to add a class to all ul and ol elements outputted by CKeditor? For example class 'editor', so that we can theme the ul/ol elements differently if they are outputted by CKeditor (with bullets or decimals).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do that for styling purposes. You can target the `ul` and `ol` elements by their parent container. The classes depends on your theme output, but consider this for the Garland theme:

```
/* Style all ul and ol elements from the body output. */
#center .node .content ul,
#center .node .content ol {
  /* Styles here */
}
```

If you are missing classes you can add those in the `page.tpl.php` and `node.tpl.php` templates.

Comment: Not possible to style on .content, because this contains other ul's which need to be styled differently + I'm trying to get a very clean HTML output without any (drupal default) exceed div's and classes, so most of those are stripped by Mothership.
However, the solution is easy. Install Display Suite and add a class (e.g. .editor) to the output of your body/text field :)

Comment: Drupal sucks in terms of clean HTML.